# Should not have a 'bearerformat' property without 'scheme: bearer' being set

Tags: postman, openapi

When importing an OpenAPI JSON file into Postman, Postman won't save the API definition because there's a syntax error with the JSON:

> Should not have a 'bearerformat' property without 'scheme: bearer' being set

[image: Postman error]

If I change the `"scheme": "Bearer"` to `"scheme": "bearer"` (lower case B) then Postman is happy, but the [schema definition](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) says it should be "Bearer".

What I don't understand is; this problem doesn't show up in a Google search, how can I be the only one having this problem? How can Postman not like the proper casing of Bearer? Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2):

The `scheme` value is [case-insensitive](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1876#issuecomment-476818843), so both `"scheme": "bearer"` and `"scheme": "Bearer"` (and even `"scheme": "BeArEr"`) are valid.

This looks like an issue with Postman. I suggest you report it to Postman's support.

As a workaround, change your definition to use lowercase `"scheme": "bearer"`.

Comment: Have done, but with the millions of people using swagger and postman, how am I the first?

Comment: I guess most people use lowercase `scheme: bearer` because that's how it's written in the [example](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#jwt-bearer-sample) in the OpenAPI spec.